# Transform (A => (M[B], M[C])) into (A => M[(B, C)])

Tags: scala, functional-programming, implicit, scalaz

I don't know the technical terminology for this, but as stated in the title, I'm looking for a function or feature of a typeclass that transforms a function outputting a pair of containers into a container containing a pair. Its signature should look like

```
def f[M[_], A, B, C](g: A => (M[B], M[C])): A => M[(B, C)]
```

To achieve this, it may be necessary to first specify a typeclass allowing a mapping `(M[A], M[B]) => M[(A, B)]` and then composing a `g` with the functionality of this typclass.

As a concrete example, suppose we have a function `f: Int => Option[Int]` and a function `g: Int => Option[Long]`. We can "pair" the functions using the arrow syntax from scalaz (`val h = f &&& g`) such that the resulting function (`h`) has type `Int => (Option[Int], Option[Long])`. We can then sequence the `Option`s by using a for-comprehension or by composing with `(a, b) => a tuple b`. How does this generalize?

EDIT:

Shortly after posting this, I discovered that the `tuple` functionality in scalaz7 was coming from the `Apply` typeclass and not from `Option` directly. Apparently this is is a weaker class than `Applicative`, which explains why this works using a monadic for-comprehension. Thus Apply should get the job done in the general case. My question is now: how can I transform the original `A => (M[B], M[C])` directly into an `A => M[(B, C)]`, without composing `Apply`'s functionality with that of the original function?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, as I don't speak scalaz, but is "a function outputting a pair of containers into a container containing a pair" not zip?  I looked for it in the scalaz docs and this looks like it does something similar to what you want: http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Zip

Answer (score 0):

Try this? I have not scalaz installed.

```
def f[M <: Monad[M[_]], A, B, C](g: A => (M[B], M[C])): A => M[(B, C)] = (a: A) => {
   g(a) match {
     // For general monads, converts (M[B],M[C]) to M[(B, C)]
     case (b, c) => b.map((_, c)).flatMap(k => k._2.map((k._1, _)))
   }
}
```

Comment: Right, I know how to do that in the specific case of Option. I was trying to generalize the approach in a more concise fashion. Please see my edit.

Comment: After investigating a bit, it may need to be done through the `Apply` type class.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but it it turns out this can be done with `Apply` alone (i.e., it can be generalized further). See my answer below. Do you know if there's a shorter, clearer way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Apply had what I needed and the below seems to work. I was hoping for more concise syntactic sugar, but it gets the job done:

```
  def pairApply[M[_] : Apply, A, B, C](g: A => (M[B], M[C])): A => M[(B, C)] = {
    g andThen (x => implicitly[Apply[M]].tuple2(x._1, x._2))
  }
```

Following [bazzargh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947404/transform-a-mb-mc-into-a-mb-c?noredirect=1#comment33250116_21947404), this can be made a little clearer by using scalaz's Zip:

```
  def zipPair[M[_] : Zip, A, B, C](g: A => (M[B], M[C])): A => M[(B, C)] = {
    g andThen (x => x._1 fzip x._2)
  }
```

The composition is still not ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

There's also `bisequence`, which lets you turn a tuple of applicatives inside out:

```
def zipPair[M[_]: Applicative, A, B, C](g: A => (M[B], M[C])): A => M[(B, C)] =
  g.andThen(_.bisequence[M, B, C])
```

It's a little more general than `Zip`, too, since it will work on any type with a `Bitraverse` instance (e.g. `Either`), not just tuples.